# Can the Lotus Designer 8.5.3 FP6 client run on Windows Server 2012 Standard VM

Tags: virtual-machine, lotus-notes, windows-server-2012

The overall picture that I am trying to achieve is for me and three other people to connect remotely to a client's network and use Lotus Designer 8.5.3 FP6 to access the client's Domino servers. We will each have our own logons to the client's Citrix environment which runs a Windows 7 desktop, then using Remote Desktop concurrently connect to PC(s) within the client's network to run Lotus Designer from there. (Lotus Designer is not available on the Citrix desktop.)

The issue is that the client is wanting to avoid having four separate physical PCs set up waiting for us to log in. They have Windows Server 2012 Standard virtual machines available.

First question: Can the Lotus Designer client 8.5.3 FP6 run on Windows Server 2012 Standard VM? I know that it is not officially supported, but is there any reason why it wouldn't work?

If it can run, then the second question: Is it possible for all four people to use remote desktop to concurrently log in to one Windows Server 2012 Standard VM, which has a separate instance of Lotus Designer 8.5.3 FP6 installed per user? (and of course run the separate instances of Designer concurrently) Or would we need four separate Windows Server 2102 Standard VMs?

Thanks for any light that can be shed on these questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Designer 8.5.3FP6 will run on Windows Server 2012 although not officially supported.

To start the designer concurrently you need to "fake" a multiuser- installation:

Before installing create an extra drive, e.g. by using "subst". 
You might need to do this twice, once for the user himself, once in an elevated prompt, so that installer can access it.

e.g. subst D: C:\NotesUserA

Then you install program and data directory into D:

After that you copy C:\NotesUserA\IBM\Notes to C:\NotesUserB\IBM\Notes, C:\NotesUserC\IBM\Notes, and so on.

In loginscript make sure, that for every user the right Folder is mapped as "D:".

That way it should be possible to start Notes concurrently in different sessions.

Comment: "...it should be possible to start Notes concurrently in different sessions"
Thanks for your response. Could I please clarify whether you have actually experienced multiple sessions of Designer running concurrently in this environment (one for each logged-on user to the VM), or if this is just a theoretical possibility? Thanks.